# How do I stop Mavericks registering random clicks?

Tags: macos, trackpad, magic-trackpad

I've been seeing odd click behaviour for a while. Whenever I have my magic trackpad plugged in, Mavericks seems to be registering a number of clicks I'm not making. This results in making the system near unusable at times as it'll randomly cause textfields I'm writing in to be highlighted and then typed over, or for full-screen videos to pause and unpause as the clicks register.

This happens during most sessions, on and off, and whether or not I'm touching the trackpad.

There are no issues if I use a mouse, as long as the magic trackpad has had the batteries removed.

Does anyone know how to fix this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that the trackpad itself was faulty. It's unclear exactly how this fault developed, but I found that switching out the trackpad for another fixed the problem. I've had no issues since.